# Is there a specific reason/ common theme why we ONLY rule like Abaye in the "יע"ל קג"ם" (Yaal Kigam)?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, amoroim

We *pasken* like Abaye in 6 places in *Shas*:

- **1)**  "**י**אוש שלא מדעת" ([Bava Metzia 21b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.21b.1-22b.7?lang=bi)) whether despair of recovering a lost item that one didn't know about is considered a conscious feeling

> **אביי אמר לא הוי יאוש** ורבא אמר הוי יאוש

- **2)** "**ע**ד זומם" ([Sanhedrin 27a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.27a.1-7?lang=bi)) whether testimony a conspiring witness may have provided is retroactively nullified after he's found to be a conspiring witness

> עד זומם **אביי אמר למפרע הוא נפסל** ורבא אמר מיכן ולהבא הוא נפס

- **3)** "**ל**חי העומד מאליו" ([Eruvin 15a](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.15a.1-19?lang=bi)) - whether a side post at the entrance to an alleyway that was not put there for the express purpose of permitting one to carry on Shabbos allows is a valid side post

> איתמר לחי העומד מאליו **אביי אמר הוי לחי** רבא אמר לא הוי לחי

- **4)** "**ק**ידושין שלא נמסרו לביאה" ([Kiddushin 51a-52a](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.51a.10-52a.4?lang=bi))- whether *kiddushin* that is not given to consummation is considered *kiddushin*

> איתמר קידושין שאין מסורין לביאה **אביי אמר הוו קידושין** רבא אמר לא הוו קידושין

- **5)** "**ג**ילוי דעת בגט" ([Gittin 34a](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.34a.3-34b.1?lang=bi))- whether disclosure of intent with regard to a bill of divorce is a significant matter/ and without it would the *get* be rendered it void

> בגלוי דעתא בגיטא קמיפלגי **דאביי סבר גלוי דעתא בגיטא לאו מלתא היא** ורבא סבר גלוי דעתא בגיטא מילתא היא

- **6)** "**מ**ומר אוכל נבלות להכעיס" ([Sanhedrin 27a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.27a.8-18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))- whether a transgressor who eats non-kosher meat to express brazeness/ *chutzpah* can be a valid witness

> מומר אוכל נבילות לתיאבון דברי הכל פסול להכעיס **אביי אמר פסול** רבא אמר כשר

---

Is there a specific reason or common theme why we only *pasken* like Abaye in these 6 cases of the "יע"ל קג"ם" (Yaal Kigam)?

---

**EDIT:** Found [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101105/how-does-the-gemara-decide-which-authority-to-rule-like) which asks about Abaye/Rava but also other *k'lalei psak*. My question is on a more micro level, ie specifically about Abaye/ Rava.

Comment: Broader duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101105/

Comment: As I answered in the duplicate question, Yaal Kagam is just an abbreviation to remember how those Halochos are ruled. Your question implies that they have clearly developed worldviews from which those Halochos follow. Unfortunately, I failed to find any consistency in their views and in all other sages. I see little consistency from Sugya to Sugya and practically no discussion of the underlying principles of their reasoning.

Comment: Similar to this one too https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43364/when-is-the-halacha-like-raba-and-when-like-abaye?rq=1